# Why is the MyRemoteImplement_Skel.class not generated when rmic MyRemoteImplement is run in the terminal?

Tags: java, rmi, stub

Here is the file MyRemoteImplement.java:

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;   //for UnicastRemoteObject

public class MyRemoteImplement extends UnicastRemoteObject implements MyRemote 
{
    public String sayHello()
    {
        return "Remote server says hello";
    }

    public MyRemoteImplement() throws RemoteException
    {
        ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            MyRemote server = new MyRemoteImplement();
            Naming.rebind("Remote Hello Server", server);
        }
        catch(Exception rex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error when registering server.");
        }
    }
}
```

I compiled this code to obtain `MyRemoteImplement.class`

I then navigated to the directory containing the file `MyRemoteImplement.class` and ran the following command in command line(Windows XP):

```
rmic MyRemoteImplement
```

According to the text book I am following, both the stub code and the skeleton code must be generated in the same directory as a consequence of running the above command.

But, I only the stub file MyRemoteImplement_stub.class is generated, not the skeleton code.

Why is the skeleton code not generated?
How to rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

The text book you are folliowing is 16 years out of date. Skeletons haven't been generated automatically since 1998. You don't need one.